# Create new sql login by passing encrypted password

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Can I create a SQL login in SQL Server 2008r2 by passing an encrypted password? I am using the following code.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
#Assign variables
$Instance   = "INHYDDPC120"
$LoginName  = "MyNewLogin"
$Password   = "ggrytyrty"#(this has to be an encrypted password)
$DBName     = "Test_SMO_Database"

#Get the server object
$Server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server") $instance

#Get the login object if it exists
$Login = $Server.Logins.Item($LoginName)

IF (!($Login))  #check to see if login already exists
{
    #it doesn't, so instantiate a new login object
    $Login = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Login") ($Server, $LoginName) 

    #make it a SQL Login
    $Login.LoginType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType]::SqlLogin

    #Create it on the server with the specified password

  # $Login.PolicyEnforcementenabled = $false
# $Login.PasswordExpirationEnabled = $false
 $Login.DefaultDatabase = $DBName     
 $Login.Create($Password)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms208084.aspx) takes a SecureString. See [Working with Passwords, Secure Strings and Credentials in Windows PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx) for how to create SecureStrings in powershell. You need to use [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849818.aspx).